# Web UI Automation login and then submit form with Powershell/Curl equivalent

Tags: forms, powershell, curl, automation, ui-automation

This is for a Windows environment: Windows 7-10 / Server 2008/2012.

I want to create a script which will automate login at a URL, navigate to a another page, and then submit a form on that page.

1. Open Internet Explorer, if not already opened
2. Login to www.example.com/login (takes me to www.example.com/home)
3. Once logged in, go to www.example.com/submit-form-data
4. Enter values for fields and submit the form via button click

At first, I thought maybe I could use something like iMacro, a greasemonkey alternative, or even bookmarklets. But that'd all still require some user intervention. If there is a macro program which can replay all the steps, perhaps I'd be open to that. Otherwise, I think I may need to employ some kind of PowerShell or Curl-like program for Windows to handle UI automation.

At least with PowerShell, I don't think submitting a form should be too bad. If that's all I had to do, I wouldn't need any help. The problem is how do I log into a site, then navigate to a specific URL, on top of submitting a form, all in the same script?

I don't have to use PowerShell. I'd be open to alternatives to Curl on Windows, whatever those might be.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you done any research on how you want to do this? Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+website+login) has been asked many times before with various answers.

Comment: One _alternative_ could be to just install curl on windows. But I'd personally prefer to use PowerShell. It's not hard to log into a site and submit some forms. (As @jamesC. Already stated out)

Comment: I appreciate the links! I had forgotten iMacros is a purchase and Kantu is free for non-commercial use. This task would be under a commercial umbrella and I'd have to get approval for purchases. I have done research on this, but I wasn't sure how to use Powershell to automate multiple pages for the same session. If need be, the powers that be can delete this question. I apologize if the question is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to drive Internet Explorer, the most painless and robust way to accomplish this is probably to use [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Many folks successfully use it on Windows via the [Selenium C# bindings](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#c) (although my favorite way to use Selenium on Windows is via the Selenium Python bindings).

If you're keen on using PowerShell, it should be possible to use Selenium from PS, although there are no official PS bindings from what I can tell.